# Get permanent array item based on string

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, hash

I need to get a random array item based on hash calculated for the string passed:

```
var animals = [ 'dog', 'cat', 'horse', 'cow', 'tiger', 'trump' ];
function getFixedItem(str, arr) {
  //magic goes here
  var hash = anyFunctionToCalcHash(str);
  var magicNumber = ???; // calculated based on hash, must be between 0 and arr.length - 1
  return arr[magicNumber];
}
```

Expected something like:

```
getFixedItem('john doe', animals); // returns cat
getFixedItem('john moe', animals); // returns horse
getFixedItem('john doe', animals); // returns cat
getFixedItem('abc102030', animals); // returns trump
getFixedItem('john doe', animals); // returns cat
```

Comment: you just need to get random num from 0 to array's length?

Comment: The magic number should be set to `5` probably. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: it isn't random, it is based on hash and must be always the same for the string passed... when I pass 'john doe', the function always returns 'cat', for example. The "magic number" is between 0 and arr.length-1... But it is always calculated the same for the string passed on first argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate a number using the ASCII codes of the input string. Then use modulus to convert that number from 0 to the length of the array.

```
...
var sum = 0;
str.split('').forEach(a => sum += a.charCodeAt(0));
var magicNumber = sum % arr.length;
return arr[magicNumber]
```

Comment: For more random results, use a better hash function like FNV. (The simple sum here, for example, will give the same number to all anagrams of the same string, and the random choice will be highly biased for short strings).